# Using Shared Objects

Tags: actionscript-3, shared-objects

I am rather new to as3. My question is...how do you update a server using a remote shared object?

Example, your in a chat room the application stores a list of users connected and is visible to all  connected clients. When a user enters or leaves the chat application the clients are updated instantly. 
Or, your in private chat room and your exchanging messages in real-time etc

Thank You

Answer (score 1):

You need Flash Media Server to use remote shared objects. (See the [documentation on SharedObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/SharedObject.html).)

If you don't have a server (computer) running Flash Media Server (software), you can take a different approach and use [Real Time Media Flow Protocol (RTMFP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Media_Flow_Protocol) to establish peer-to-peer connections. See for example the following tutorial for a rundown on how to use the classes in the [flash.net package](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/package-detail.html) to create a P2P chat client: [Create a Chat App Using Flash and Peer to Peer](http://designupdate.com/blog/2011/03/28/create-a-chat-app-using-flash-and-peer-to-peer/). Also see the [documentation for the NetGroup class](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/NetGroup.html).

Comment: Thank you for your reply Joshua. I should off mentioned i am using FMS development server 4.5.

Comment: Below is my code. I admit i only about 50% what i am doing. I was attempting to use the SharedObject,send method for the client to call the server.